# Error with starting new thread

Tags: java, android

When I hover with mouse over this code, it says: `Thread() in Thread cannot be applied to (java.lang.Runnable)`.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {   
           uploadFile(imagepath);   
    }
 }).start();
```

When I run project, I get error: `cannot find symbol constructor Thread(<anonymous java.lang.Runnable>)`

I tried to call `uploadFile(imagepath);` without new thread, but app crashes on this line in code.

Does anyone know where is the problem and how to fix this?

Comment: You should probably avoid creating Threads like this, and instead use AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Post your exception stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chance that somewhere in your package you have create a class called `Thread` that is hiding the java.lang.Thread class.

Try specifying the Thread class using the full qualified name like this:

```
new java.lang.Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {   
           uploadFile(imagepath);   
    }
 }).start();
```